# How do I automatically resize an image for a mobile site?

Tags: html, css, image

I tried a Google search on this and still cannot figure out how to resize an image by its width for various mobile devices. Here is my attempt:

CSS:

```
img.test {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;   user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/style.css">
    </head>
    <img class="test"  src="../includes/foo.jpg">
```

But the image is still being loaded with its original scaling. I am a css and html newb so any help would be great!

Edit:

Thanks for the responses. Here is a revised version that now works.

HTML:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;  user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/style.css">
    </head>
    <body width = "device-width">
        <img class="test"  src="../includes/buoy_map.jpg">
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you given any of the parent elements of the image a width?

Comment: Your `img` tag should be inside `body`. You don't actually _have_ a body tag, so add one :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css with doesn't have any effect as the outer element doesn't have a width defined (and body is missing as well).

A different approach is to deliver already scaled images. http://www.sencha.com/products/io/ for example delivers the image already scaled down depending on the viewing device.

Answer (score 68):

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Should set the image to take up 100% of its containing element.

Comment: This is useful, in certain circumstances, but it will ignore the aspect ratio of your image, potentially skewing it.

Comment: in that case it should include height: auto;

Answer (score 25):

```
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I need to exempt a logo on the page. Can a particular image be exempted?

Comment: It's ok now. I reduced min-width to 100px.

Answer (score 17):

if you use **bootstrap 3** , just add **img-responsive** class in your img tag

```
<img class="img-responsive"  src="...">
```

if you use **bootstrap 4**, add **img-fluid** class in your img tag

```
<img class="img-fluid"  src="...">
```

which does the staff: 
    max-width: 100%, height: auto, and display:block to the image

Comment: I don't know why someone Voted Down this answer. This works well for me. The image squeezes well in Mobile browser. Thank you.

Comment: height: auto; did the trick for me. Now my images are resizing accordingly to the resolution of the mobile device. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me, but then I am using Bootstrap 4 so it was built in. For the OP that is probably not the case.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following css to resize the image for mobile view

```
object-fit: scale-down; max-width: 100%
```

Comment: thank you so much for showing me the object-fit property. It was exactly what i was looking for and led me to even discovering objectposition.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it worked best to add this in image css: `max-width:100%;` and NOT specify image width and height in html parameters. This adjusted the width to fit in device screen while adjusting height automatically. Otherwise height might be distorted.

Answer (score 1):

```css
img.thatimage
{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

/* This is how you set the style for a certain image */
```

```html
<img class="thatimage" src="your_image_path" alt="" style="">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).